# python rply reverse parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, ply

I'm using `rply` and Python3.6 to create a lexer and a parser for a little privat project.

But what I noticed is that the parser appears to flip the order of the lexerstream.

This is the file I'm parsing:

```
let test:string = "test";
print(test);
```

Lexer output:

```
Token('LET', 'let')
Token('NAME', 'test')
Token('COLON', ':')
Token('NAME', 'string')
Token('EQUALS', '=')
Token('STRING', '"test"')
Token('SEMI_COLON', ';')
Token('PRINT', 'print')
Token('OPEN_PARENS', '(')
Token('STRING', '"test"')
Token('CLOSE_PARENS', ')')
Token('SEMI_COLON', ';')
```

As you can see it is in the order of the script.

I use the parser to create a variable with name `test`, type `string` and value `test`. Then I want to print the variable.

It does create the variable but when I want to print it out, there is nothing.

But when I flip the script like this

```
print(test);
let test:string = "test";
```

it is able to print the value correctly.

The two parser 'rules' look like this:
Print:

```
@self.pg.production('expression : PRINT OPEN_PARENS expression CLOSE_PARENS SEMI_COLON expression')
def print_s(p):
    ...
```

Create variable:

```
@self.pg.production('expression : LET expression COLON expression EQUALS expression SEMI_COLON expression')
def create_var(p):
    ...
```

So my question is: How can I flip the order in which the content is parsed?

Edit: I looked for similar questions or problems and also in the documentation but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a somewhat simpler example; hopefully, you can see the pattern.

The key insight is that reduction actions (that is, the parser functions) are executed when the production's match has been fully parsed. That means that if a production contains non-terminals, the actions for those non-terminals are executed before the action for the whole production.

It should be clear why this is true. Every production action depends on the semantic values of all of the components, and in the case of non-terminals those values are produced by running the corresponding actions.

Now, consider these two very similar ways to parse a `list` of `thing`s. In both cases, we assume there is a base production which recognises an empty `list` (`list :`) and does nothing.

1. Right recursion:

   ```
   list : thing list
   ```
2. Left recursion:

   ```
   list : list thing
   ```

In both cases, the action prints the `thing`, which is `p[0]` in the right-recursive case, and `p[1]` in the left-recursive one.

The right-recursive production will cause the `thing`s to be printed in reverse order, because printing the `thing` doesn't happen until after the internal `list` is parsed (and it's components are printed).

But the left-recursive production will print the `thing`s in left-to-right order, for the same reason. The difference is tgat in the left-recursive case, the internal (recursive) `list` contains the initial `thing`s while in the right-recursive case, the `list` contains the final `thing`s.

If you were just building a Python list of `thing`s, this probably wouldn't matter much, since execution order wouldn't be important. It's only visible in this example because the action has a *side-effect* (printing a value), which makes execution order visible.

There are other techniques to order actions, in the rare cases where it is really necessary. But best practice is to always use left-recursion whenever it is syntactically practical. Left-recursive parsers are more efficient because the parser doesn't need to accumulate a stack of incomplete productions. And left-recursion is often better for your actions as well.

Here, for example, the left-recursive action could append the new value (`p[0].append(p[1]); return p[0]`), while the right-recursive action needs to create a new list (`return [p[0] + p[1]`). Since repeated appending is on average linear time while repeated concatenation is quadratic, the left-recursive parser is more scalable for large lists.

Comment: Okay, first: Thanks for this reply. That is honestly one of the best answers to this topic I've seen. So I basically have to watch the order of my parser if an expression depends on another expression? Because I thought the parser just goes through the lexerstream token for token.

Comment: @llj97: the parser does parse left to right. And it executes every reduction action immediately at the right-hand edge. But that doesn't magically move a print statement backwards in time. The print statement in a reduction action is executed when the reduction action is executed, not when whatever it's printing is tokenised. That's not different from any program. When you `printf('%d\n", a);` that happens when the `printf` is called, not when `a`'s value is set...

Comment: Having said that, you don't normally have to think about execution order because it doesn't matter. Every non-terminal's value us computed before it's used. You only have to think about it if you insert side-effects into the computation, like printing things out...

Comment: Oh okay, now I got it. Thank you very much!